# Jenkins - login

Tags: nginx, freebsd, jenkins

I have a Jenkins installed on a freebsd jail and I access it internally on https through nginx (proxy_pass _https://ip-jail:port),
my problem is that I would like to go directly to the login (sign in) page and not pass through the anonymous dashboard to connect (once here you can get to the login page by accessing a link), if there is some configuration that I overlooked, missed, please tell me,
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you disable anonymous access you will be taken to the login page instead of the anonymous dashboard if you are not logged in to Jenkins.

Comment: I get access denied when I remove the anonymous access.